# How can I search ~/Library with the command find on my mac?

Tags: unix, find

I want to find all the files a piece of software has left in my system.
In the terminal I type:

`$ find /Users -name software -print`

And every time find tries to look into a folder within the Library directory, Terminal returns "operation not permitted".
So I tried:

`$ sudo find /Users -name software -print`

Same result

So I finally enabled super user, logged in with command `su`, entered my command: same result.

1 - I do not understand why even the super user is not allowed to search the library.
2 - what is the work around?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Remove the dot before Library, that is, `~/Library`.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. The mistake is in the title of the question (I'll try to edit it). But the question remains.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.

Terminal needs to be added in the System Preferences/Security and Privacy/ full disk access!